# PHP create Form to CSV and Send to email as attachment

Tags: php, html

I am creating a webpage that has a form, and in that form I need to save it as csv and I need it to be sent to an email  as an  attachment file, how do I do that?

First how can I output all of the inputs to csv, then save it as csv file and automatically attach it to email.

Below is the code I've tried :

## PHP

```
<?php

    // define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $countryErr = $confirmErr = "";

function clean_text($string)
{
 $string = trim($string);
 $string = stripslashes($string);
 $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
 return $string;
}

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
 
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "sample@email";
    $email_subject = "Form Submission";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        exit();
    }
 
    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['country']) ||
        !isset($_POST['confirm_email'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }
 
    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $country = $_POST['country']; // not required
    $confirm_email = $_POST['confirm_email']; // required
 
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
 
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  } 
 
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    
      if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    
    $email_message = "Subsciber Details Information.\n\n";
     
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Full Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Country: ".clean_string($country)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Confirmed Email: ".clean_string($confirm_email)."\n";
 
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
    
    /*Autoreply Sender Name*/
 $headerss = "FROM: Comapny name <companyname@email.com>\r\n";
    
    /* Prepare autoresponder subject */
$respond_subject = "Sign-up for CompanyName Mailing List Completed";
    
/* Prepare autoresponder message */
$respond_message = "Thank you for your interest in sign-up for our mailing list.
We will keep you updated on CompanyName.

In the case that this email is unexpected, it will be troubling, but please inquire through the given address.

Congress Secretariat of CompanyName
subs-apsr companyname@email.com

";
    
/* Send the response message using mail() function */

mail($email_from, $respond_subject, $respond_message, $headerss);
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
header('Location: thank-you-page.html');
    
?>
<!-- include your own success html here -->
<?php
}
?>
```

## HTML form

```
<form name="contactform" method="post">
                <div class="keep__me__posted">

                    <p>Please sign up NOW.</p>
                    <p class="margin__p">We will keep you updated on CompanyName</p>

                    <div class="input__form">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30" value="" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input__form">
                        <label for="country">Country</label>
                        <input type="text" id="country" name="country" maxlength="30" size="30" value="" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input__form">
                        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" value="" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input__form">
                        <label for="confirm_email">Confirm Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="confirm_email" name="confirm_email" maxlength="30" size="30" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input__form submit">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                                <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="submit" onclick="checkEmail()">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: and what problem are you having with this code, specifically?

Comment: CSV is about storing "table-like" data as text. You have a single form with a fistful of fields. Are you sure about CSV? Or, perhaps, do you want to append the result to an existing CSV?

Comment: I am asking for a help. @ADyson

Comment: @tevemadar yes it should be csv file. whenver I input a data to the form, it will output as csv file and it should be attached to the email

Comment: help with what, **specifically**? There's a lot of code here...which part of it is giving you a problem? Please explain any errors and/or unexpected behaviour you're seeing. You've told us what you _want_ the code to do, but not what it does _now_. Don't expect people to spend their time to work it out, when you can just tell us. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. If your answer to that is "The code doesn't do what I want because I haven't written the relevant part yet", then that means you haven't done enough research. You can easily research online for 1) how to put data into a CSV file, 2) how to save a file to disk and 3) how to attach files to an email. Nothing is stopping you from making some kind of attempt for yourself. We're not here to do basic research or make generic examples for you, especially examples which already exist online. We'll _help_ you, not just write whole features for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To write in your csv file, you can  take a look at
[this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) :

```
$file = fopen('yourFile.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($file, array('this','is some', 'csv "stuff", you know.'));
fclose($file);
```

To send this file with the mail, I think the easier option is to use PHPMailer.
Don't really know how to use it, but you can easily find it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail). You firstly need to download and instal the package found [on gitHub](http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and then use it like this :

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->SetFrom('you@example.com', 'Your Name'); //Name is optional
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinationaddress@example.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );

return $email->Send();
```